# Splitting a data frame character column into an arbitrary number of columns with dynamic column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, reshape

I currently have a data frame with a character column that has different column data embedded into it:

```
column
Name1 A=a;B=b;C=c;X
Name2 A=a;C=c;D=d;E=e;X
Name3 Y
Name4 A=z;B=y;Z
...
NameN E=f;X
```

The different bits of data in this column is arbitrary with no particular ordering. I've figured out how to turn the column into a list (i.e. using stringr::str_split) such that:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Name1"  "A=a"  "B=b"  "C=c"  "X"
[[2]]
[1] "Name2"  "A=a"  "C=c"  "D=d"  "E=e"  "X"
[[3]]
[1] "Name3"  "Y"
[[4]]
[1] "Name4"  "A=z"  "B=y"  "Z"
...
[[N]]
[1] "NameN"  "E=f"  "X"
```

But given that some of the embedded columns are only in some rows, this cant be easily cast as a data frame, especially without knowing the new column names ahead of time.

The desired result would be:

```
column  A  B  C  D  E ... Type
Name1   a  b  c  NA NA... X
Name2   a  NA c  d  e ... X
Name3   NA NA NA NA NA... Y
Name4   z  y  NA NA NA... Z
...
NameN   NA NA NA NA f ... X
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best will be to use `purrr:map_dfr()` for processing `strsplit()` output. It allows an arbitrary operation on elements of a list and binds results rowwise into a data frame. Additionally I will use `purrr::transpose()` for flipping list of pair into pair of lists and `purrr::as_vector()` for turning a list into a vector.

Assuming that first and last bit always goes into `column` and `Type` respectively, the solution is:

```
library(purrr)

column %>%
  strsplit(' |;') %>%
  map_dfr(~{
    column <- .x[1]
    Type <- .x[length(.x)]

    bits <- .x[-c(1,length(x))] %>%
              strsplit('=') %>%
              transpose()

    result <- c(colimn, bits[[2]], Type)
    names(results) <- c('colimn', as_vector(bits[[1]]), 'Type')
  })
```